# MongoDB: &and with $match

Tags: mongodb, match, multiple-conditions

Hi: I'm using multiple $match and $and operator, I've got error:

```
uncaught exception: aggregate failed: {
    "errmsg" : "exception: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$and'",
    "code" : 16436,
    "ok" : 0
}
```

my db.version returns 3.0.4. According to MongoDb document, this should be supported in version 3.0.x. Is there anything I did wrong here? Thanks for any help.

Here is my query:

```
db.getCollection('plannedVoyageStops').aggregate(    
    {$and : {$match:{ "scenarioId":"xxxx"},$match:{"action":"remove"}} },  
    {$unwind : "$plannedCMSs" },
    {$project: {_id: 0, scenarioId: 1, 
                "shipmentNumber":"$plannedCMSs.shipmentNumber",
                "vsId": 1, "stopSeqNum":1, "trade":1,
                "svvd": 1,                
                "action":"$plannedCMSs.action"
                }
    }
);
```

single match condition works just fine and the result collection contains all types of action, I intended to get only those with action=="remove", ideally.

```
# db.getCollection('plannedVoyageStops').aggregate(
#     {$match:{ "scenarioId":"xxxx"}},
#     {$unwind : "$plannedCMSs" },
#     {$project: {_id: 0, scenarioId: 1,
#                 "shipmentNumber":"$plannedCMSs.shipmentNumber",
#                 "vsId": 1, "stopSeqNum":1, "trade":1,
#                 "svvd": 1,
#                 "action":"$plannedCMSs.action"
#                 }
#     }
# );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you have the `$match` key twice. That is not allowed. If you want to match two conditions within [$and](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/and/) operator, you need an array of conditions. However, `$and` is not needed here: in a mongo query, `$and` is implicit using just commas. Simply assign a JSON query to your`$match`: try

```
db.getCollection('plannedVoyageStops').aggregate(    
    {$match : { "scenarioId":"xxxx","action":"remove"}},  
    {$unwind : "$plannedCMSs" },
    {$project: {_id: 0, scenarioId: 1, 
                "shipmentNumber":"$plannedCMSs.shipmentNumber",
                "vsId": 1, "stopSeqNum":1, "trade":1,
                "svvd": 1,                
                "action":"$plannedCMSs.action"
                }
    }
);
```